# How to make sense out of bluetooth characteristics (Cycling Speed and Cadence) data in flutter?

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, cross-platform, gatt, bluetooth-gatt

I am getting following output while cycling using a smart trainer which is attached to Bluetooth sensor which gives cycling speed and cadence values:
flutter: [0, 23, 19, 9, 20, 20, 22, 14, 28, 24, 227, 13, 31, 22, 236, 104, 18, 29, 34, 10]
flutter: [64, 24, 10, 19, 10, 7, 30, 22, 24, 20, 245, 26, 38, 22, 241, 16, 22, 23, 34, 15]
flutter: [128, 27, 20, 30, 17, 113, 17, 32, 13, 16, 20, 221, 21, 12, 15, 10, 18, 14, 35, 238]
flutter: [192, 26, 29, 20, 251, 100, 9, 24, 16, 20, 2, 22, 32, 242, 19, 17, 14, 20, 35, 9]
flutter: [0, 23, 19, 9, 20, 20, 22, 14, 28, 24, 227, 13, 31, 22, 236, 104, 18, 29, 34, 10]
flutter: [64, 24, 10, 19, 10, 7, 30, 22, 25, 20, 245, 26, 234, 22, 113, 16, 22, 23, 34, 15]
flutter: [128, 27, 20, 30, 17, 113, 17, 32, 13, 16, 20, 221, 21, 12, 15, 10, 18, 14, 35, 238]
flutter: [192, 26, 29, 20, 251, 100, 9, 24, 16, 20, 2, 22, 32, 242, 19, 17, 14, 20, 35, 9]
flutter: [0, 23, 19, 9, 20, 20, 22, 14, 28, 24, 227, 13, 31, 22, 236, 104, 18, 29, 34, 10]
flutter: [64, 24, 10, 19, 10, 7, 30, 22, 25, 20, 245, 26, 234, 22, 113, 16, 22, 23, 34, 15]
flutter: [128, 27, 20, 30, 17, 113, 17, 32, 13, 16, 20, 221, 21, 12, 15, 10, 18, 14, 35, 238]
flutter: [192, 26, 29, 20, 251, 100, 9, 24, 16, 20, 2, 22, 32, 242, 19, 17, 14, 20, 35, 9]
flutter: [0, 23, 19, 9, 20, 20, 22, 14, 28, 24, 227, 13, 31, 22, 236, 104, 18, 29, 34, 10]
flutter: [64, 24, 10, 19, 10, 7, 30, 22, 25, 20, 245, 26, 239, 22, 113, 16, 22, 23, 34, 15]
flutter: [128, 27, 20, 30, 17, 113, 17, 32, 13, 16, 20, 223, 21, 12, 15, 10, 18, 14, 35, 238]
flutter: [192, 26, 29, 20, 251, 100, 9, 24, 16, 20, 2, 22, 32, 242, 19, 17, 14, 20, 35, 9]
flutter: [0, 23, 19, 9, 20, 20, 22, 14, 28, 24, 227, 13, 31, 22, 236, 104, 18, 29, 34, 10]
flutter: [64, 24, 10, 19, 10, 7, 30, 22, 25, 20, 245, 26, 236, 22, 113, 16, 22, 23, 34, 15]
flutter: [128, 27, 20, 30, 17, 113, 17, 32, 13, 16, 20, 219, 21, 12, 15, 10, 18, 14, 35, 238]
flutter: [192, 26, 29, 20, 251, 100, 9, 24, 16, 20, 2, 22, 32, 249, 19, 17, 14, 20, 35, 9]
flutter: [0, 23, 19, 9, 20, 20, 22, 14, 28, 24, 227, 13, 31, 22, 233, 104, 18, 29, 34, 10]
flutter: [64, 24, 10, 19, 10, 7, 30, 22, 25, 20, 245, 16, 237, 29, 113, 16, 149, 23, 34, 15]
flutter: [128, 27, 151, 30, 102, 113, 27, 32, 13, 97, 20, 217, 21, 12, 15, 6, 25, 14, 35, 238]
flutter: [192, 72, 29, 146, 251, 100, 5, 24, 16, 20, 17, 22, 32, 254, 98, 17, 14, 20, 35, 126]
flutter: [0, 145, 65, 31, 20, 20, 5, 14, 28, 24, 227, 113, 31, 22, 226, 104, 9, 29, 34, 10]
flutter: [64, 100, 10, 19, 10, 7, 8, 22, 25, 20, 245, 120, 252, 12, 113, 16, 151, 23, 57, 15]
flutter: [128, 27, 149, 30, 111, 113, 115, 32, 13, 135, 20, 201, 21, 12, 15, 28, 8, 14, 35, 238]
flutter: [192, 199, 29, 111, 251, 100, 31, 24, 16, 20, 21, 13, 32, 225, 132, 17, 14, 20, 35, 119]
flutter: [0, 108, 206, 19, 50, 20, 1, 14, 28, 24, 227, 115, 31, 22, 245, 104, 74, 29, 34, 10]
flutter: [64, 102, 10, 19, 10, 7, 4, 22, 25, 20, 245, 17, 254, 13, 113, 54, 151, 23, 122, 15]
flutter: [128, 27, 149, 30, 111, 113, 26, 32, 13, 187, 20, 203, 21, 12, 15, 29, 9, 14, 35, 238]
flutter: [192, 33, 29, 107, 251, 100, 30, 24, 16, 20, 26, 63, 32, 230, 184, 17, 14, 20, 35, 119]
flutter: [0, 104, 40, 20, 61, 20, 14, 14, 28, 24, 227, 115, 31, 22, 248, 104, 17, 29, 34, 10]
flutter: [64, 102, 10, 19, 10, 7, 3, 22, 25, 20, 245, 60, 244, 52, 113, 30, 105, 23, 33, 15]
flutter: [128, 27, 107, 16, 111, 113, 55, 32, 13, 200, 20, 200, 21, 12, 15, 43, 48, 14, 35, 238]
flutter: [192, 29, 29, 107, 251, 100, 40, 24, 16, 20, 31, 22, 32, 230, 203, 17, 14, 20, 35, 119]
flutter: [0, 104, 20, 19, 20, 20, 11, 14, 28, 24, 227, 114, 31, 22, 247, 104, 175, 29, 34, 10]
flutter: [64, 103, 10, 19, 10, 7, 4, 22, 25, 20, 245, 175, 249, 0, 113, 16, 108, 23, 159, 15]
flutter: [128, 27, 110, 30, 110, 113, 164, 32, 13, 12, 20, 211, 21, 12, 15, 25, 4, 14, 35, 238]
flutter: [192, 5, 29, 105, 251, 100, 26, 24, 16, 20, 19, 22, 32, 254, 15, 17, 14, 20, 35, 118]
flutter: [0, 106, 12, 25, 20, 20, 7, 14, 28, 24, 227, 114, 31, 22, 253, 104, 197, 29, 34, 10]
flutter: [64, 103, 10, 19, 10, 7, 14, 22, 25, 20, 245, 94, 224, 24, 113, 16, 104, 23, 245, 15]
flutter: [128, 27, 106, 30, 147, 113, 85, 32, 13, 108, 20, 213, 21, 12, 15, 7, 28, 14, 35, 238]
flutter: [192, 234, 29, 98, 251, 100, 4, 24, 16, 20, 9, 22, 32, 252, 111, 17, 14, 20, 35, 139]
flutter: [0, 97, 227, 2, 20, 20, 29, 14, 28, 24, 227, 142, 31, 22, 234, 104, 177, 29, 34, 10]
flutter: [64, 155, 10, 19, 10, 7, 21, 22, 25, 20, 245, 170, 227, 31, 113, 16, 110, 23, 129, 15]
flutter: [128, 27, 108, 30, 103, 113, 161, 32, 13, 157, 20, 214, 21, 12, 15, 2, 27, 14, 35, 238]
flutter: [192, 67, 29, 10, 251, 100, 1, 24, 16, 20, 0, 22, 32, 251, 158, 17, 14, 20, 35, 127]
flutter: [0, 9, 74, 8, 20, 20, 20, 14, 28, 24, 227, 29, 31, 22, 229, 104, 28, 29, 34, 10]
flutter: [64, 8, 10, 19, 10, 7, 31, 22, 25, 20, 245, 26, 227, 22, 113, 16, 22, 23, 44, 15]
flutter: [128, 27, 20, 30, 17, 113, 17, 32, 13, 16, 20, 218, 21, 12, 15, 10, 18, 14, 35, 238]
flutter: [192, 26, 29, 20, 251, 100, 9, 24, 16, 20, 2, 22, 32, 247, 19, 17, 14, 20, 35, 9]
flutter: [0, 23, 19, 9, 20, 20, 22, 14, 28, 24, 227, 13, 31, 22, 239, 104, 18, 29, 34, 10]
flutter: [64, 24, 10, 19, 10, 7, 30, 22, 25, 20, 245, 26, 238, 22, 113, 16, 22, 23, 34, 15]
flutter: [128, 27, 20, 30, 17, 113, 17, 32, 13, 16, 20, 223, 21, 12, 15, 10, 18, 14, 35, 238]
flutter: [192, 26, 29, 20, 251, 100, 9, 24, 16, 20, 2, 22, 32, 241, 19, 17, 14, 20, 35, 9]
flutter: [0, 23, 19, 9, 20, 20, 22, 14, 28, 24, 227, 13, 31, 22, 238, 104, 18, 29, 34, 10]
flutter: [64, 24, 10, 19, 10, 7, 30, 22, 25, 20, 245, 26, 234, 22, 113, 16, 22, 23, 34, 15]
flutter: [128, 27, 20, 30, 17, 113, 17, 32, 13, 16, 20, 222, 21, 12, 15, 10, 18, 14, 35, 238]
flutter: [192, 26, 29, 20, 251, 100, 9, 24, 16, 20, 2, 22, 32, 242, 19, 17, 14, 20, 35, 9]
flutter: [0, 23, 19, 9, 20, 20, 22, 14, 28, 24, 227, 13, 31, 22, 239, 104, 18, 29, 34, 10]
flutter: [64, 24, 10, 19, 10, 7, 30, 22, 25, 20, 245, 26, 234, 22, 113, 16, 22, 23, 34, 15]

Can somebody help me in decoding this data or at least understand how to get the speed and cadence data from it?

Comment: You have got a lot of raw data there, I recommend looking at the datasheet for whatever device you are using. I recommend you store these data values and put them inside of a database. Create a database with 3 data points time, speed and cadence. As it is an array of data you can simply work through the elements of the array and store them depending on the type of data they are or the position.